# Is there a way to have attachments automatically uploaded to google drive?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, microsoft-outlook-2013, google-drive

Is it possible to do the following? I receive e-mails from certain people containing attachments and I want them to be uploaded to Google Drive. The e-mail account I receive them on isn't gmail, but I could easily enough setup and auto forwarding rule to gmail. I'm using Outlook 2013. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: There is a Lifehacker article I read a few years ago, it provided a link to a website, the name of the script was Send to `Google Drive v2.0` in works by creating a time based google script event.  It only works with emails within a Google Account.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of is to use this IFTTT recipe: [Save my email attachments to Google Drive](https://ifttt.com/recipes/99068).

It will require email sent to Gmail and, of course, to sign up for If-This-Then-That.